# How to Stop Data Transformation when Using "summaryBy" Function in R's "doBy" Package

Tags: r

I am trying to run some summary statistics on a large data set where the groups = (Entry + Plant).  I am using the summaryBy() function, and it appears to be working fine for most of my variables.  It is, however, transforming one of my variables (YieldPlant) using an unknown function and improperly calculating means and standard deviations.  Here is some sample output:

```
> library(doBy)
> SP.data <- read.csv("~/Desktop/2014 Summer Research/Within-Line Variation Trial/2014 Heirloom Variation Trial.csv", na.string = c("NA"))
> head(SP.data$YieldPlant, n=10)    [1] NA  NA  NA  NA  16.16 18.58 11.2  10.95 11.61 13.94
> summaryTRAITS <- summaryBy(YieldPlant ~ Entry + Plant, data=SP.data, FUN = function(Plant) { c(m=mean(Plant, na.rm=T), s=sd(Plant, na.rm=T))})
> head(summaryTRAITS$YieldPlant.m, n=10)     [1]  NaN 307.8571 444.0000 364.0000 179.5714 354.2857 592.1429 521.3333 729.8571 322.4286
```

The "YieldPlant" should be much smaller than R is recognizing.  I'd appreciate any help you all can offer.  Thanks!

Hannah

Comment: "Why isn't this code working" types of questions need to provide enough code AND data to allow investigation.

Comment: As it turns out, the summaryBy() function sometime reads variables as a factor.  I had to use this adjusted code to get it to read properly: summaryBy(as.numeric(as.character(YieldPlant)) ~ Entry + Plant, data=SP.data, FUN = function(Plant) { c(m=mean(Plant, na.rm=T), s=sd(Plant, na.rm=T))}).  I'm not sure why this function did this, but thanks for checking out the question anyways, @BondedDust

Comment: In all likelihood it wasn't `summaryBy`'s fault. You didn't recognize the problem because `print.data.frame` displays numeric and factor-class values without quotes. The problem probably goes back to the point at which you created the data.frame in the first place. If you wanted to prevent this in the future you could set `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` in a .Rprofile file.